# How do I remove trailing zeros from a character function in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have used the label_percent() function with a large dataset to get percentages that look something like this...

```
data <- c('65.4500%', '75.6500%', '-34.5500%','-2.0400%')
```

I would like to achieve the following output

```
data <- c('64.45%','75.65%','-34.55%','-2.04%)
```

Is there a simple way in R to remove the trailing zeros (preferably without having to convert the percentage values back to numeric)?

Comment: `gsub('0','',data,fixed=T)` should be tried

Comment: @Duck `0.01%` …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace all the 0's which come in the end of the string along with `%` sign with just `%` sign.

```
gsub('0*%$', '%', data)
#[1] "65.45%"  "75.65%"  "-34.55%" "-2.04%"
```

Comment: You can also use ```.``` in the regex before 0 so you do not have a point like 100.%

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
data <- c('65.4500%', '75.6500%', '-34.5500%','-2.0400%',"0.0010100%")
gsub("(.*)0.+(%)","\\1\\2",data)
# [1] "65.45%"   "75.65%"   "-34.55%"  "-2.04%"   "0.00101%"
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without omitting zeros that come before decimal point (ie  -2.0400%)? Thanks

Comment: @DanielGrant Could you give an example? -2.0400% has no zeros before decimal point